# How to center-align content projected into a button in PrimeNG 10?

Tags: css, button, primeng

In PrimeNG 9, I could center-align the content projected into a button. Does anybody know how this can be achieved in PrimeNG 10?

```
<div class="ui-g ui-fluid" >
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <button pButton>
      <div>Content</div>
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Button Rendered in PrimeNG 9:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q2sW.png]

I already submitted an issue of having the `&nbsp;` rendered when the label is missing.
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9482

Answer (score 2):

Add `style="width: 100%"` to your Content div.

And you can set `label=" "` to avoid the `&nbsp;` char while waiting fix from PrimeNG team.

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-button-demo-1sx3vk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

PrimeNG's documentation is not up-to-date when it comes to primeflex, please check primeflex's documentation directly instead:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/

Below code snippet centers a button, you can re-use that to center content within the button as well:

```
<div class="flex justify-content-center">
    <button pButton type="button" label="Submit"></button>
</div>
```